# Check if window.onbeforeunload has been triggered by a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I have a function like this to prompt the user to confirm they want to navigate away from the page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return "You may lose any unsaved changes.";
};
```

Now I'd like to check whether this is a just a page refresh (F5), and not render the message in this case. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible, there is no way to find out if the refresh button of browser was pressed.

Comment: Hmmm dammit. I may have to rethink. Cheers.